# How to install interrupt handler for IPI in powerpc using MPIC?

Tags: interrupt, powerpc, interrupt-handling

Do CPUs (specifically powerpc) allow an interrupt handler to be installed for IPIs (inter processor interrupts) ? The MPIC I am using supports 4 IPIs per core and it has registers for setting the vector and priority of these IPIs, but where should I install the interrupt handler ? The CPU core has IVORs (Interrupt Vector Offset Registers) for setting interrupt handlers for external interrupt, internal interrupt, timer interrupts, exceptions, etc, but nothing for IPIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPIs come in on the EE vector. You have to find from the MPIC why you got interrupted, in the EE exception handler.